# How to clean Mapbox-gl data on map

Tags: jquery, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm new to Mapbox-gl and I made my code using mostly the snippets I found online.

So far, my code allows you to select three spots on map and it will show the 
 driving directions between the three markers.
The user cannot change the markers he/she selected.

I'd want to know if there's a way to remove the marker by clicking on a little close button above it. If it is not possible to handle this way, having a button to reset the markers and directions would suffice.

Bellow is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Test MapBoxGL</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v3.1.1/mapbox-gl-directions.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v3.1.1/mapbox-gl-directions.css' type='text/css' />
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
.marker {
  background-image: url('mapbox-icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGlzaHRhYXIiLCJhIjoiY2psM2lia3oyMTRqcTNqcXkxZHp2cWZ3NiJ9.8KTN3HeYdT8I0Czl2n5JcQ';
var map;
var directions;
var latsAndLngs = '';



// generate map
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
  center: [-2.2423008303912297, 53.476834517811255],
  zoom: 10
});

var testVar = '';
var firstMarkerCoordinates = '';
var secondMarkerCoordinates = '';
var thirdMarkerCoordinates = '';
map.on('click', function(e) {

    console.log(e.lngLat);

        // create a HTML element for each feature
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'marker';
        var markersQty = $('.marker').length;

        if(markersQty < 3)
        {
            if(markersQty == 0)
            {
                firstMarkerLng = e.lngLat.lng;
                firstMarkerLat = e.lngLat.lat;
                firstMarkerCoordinates = (firstMarkerLng +','+firstMarkerLat);
            }

            //second marker created by click
            if(markersQty == 1)
            {
                secondMarkerLng = e.lngLat.lng;
                secondMarkerLat = e.lngLat.lat;
                secondMarkerCoordinates = (secondMarkerLng +','+secondMarkerLat);
                latsAndLngs = firstMarkerCoordinates+';'+secondMarkerCoordinates;

                featuresData = [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [firstMarkerLng, firstMarkerLat]
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [secondMarkerLng, secondMarkerLat]
                    }
                }];

                //getDirectionz();
            }

            //third marker created by click
            if(markersQty == 2)
            {
                thirdMarkerLng = e.lngLat.lng;
                thirdMarkerLat = e.lngLat.lat;
                thirdMarkerCoordinates = (thirdMarkerLng +','+thirdMarkerLat);
                latsAndLngs = firstMarkerCoordinates+';'+secondMarkerCoordinates+';'+thirdMarkerCoordinates;

                featuresData = [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [firstMarkerLng, firstMarkerLat]
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [secondMarkerLng, secondMarkerLat]
                    }
                }, {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [thirdMarkerLng , thirdMarkerLat]
                    }
                }];

                getDirectionz();
            }

            console.log(latsAndLngs);
            // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
            new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                .setLngLat([e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat])
                .addTo(map);
        }



    });

// change mouse action on enter / leave in marker
map.on('mouseenter', 'markers', function () {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
map.on('mouseleave', 'markers', function () {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});


<!-- map.on('load', () => { -->

  <!-- getDirectionz(); -->

<!-- }) -->

function getDirectionz()
{
    $.get(`https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/${latsAndLngs}?access_token=${mapboxgl.accessToken}&geometries=geojson`, data => {

    map.addLayer({
      id: 'route',
      type: 'line',
      source: {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          type: 'Feature',
          properties: {},
          geometry: data.routes[0].geometry,
        },
      },
      layout: {
        'line-join': 'round',
        'line-cap': 'round',
      },
      paint: {
        'line-color': '#ff7e5f',
        'line-width': 8,
      },
    })



    map.addSource("markers", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": featuresData
        }
    });
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "markers",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "markers",
        "paint": {
            "circle-radius": 7,
            "circle-color": "#3bb2d0"
        },
    });
    // center map on markers
    var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
    featuresData.forEach(function(feature) {
        bounds.extend(feature.geometry.coordinates);
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  })
}
//map.addControl(directions);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion is welcome,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do. just push all the marker in one array, and then you can remove the markers on any event like on-click of button or any.
example:-

//Initialise and push markers.

```
var selectedMarker = [];
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(image)
                .setLngLat(coordinates)
                .addTo(map);
selectedMarker.push(marker);
```

//To remove

```
if (selectedMarker!==null) {
  for (var i = selectedMarker.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectedMarker[i].remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you flush or clean a mapbox-gl map:

```
document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "";
```